# Sound on pseudoelements using CSS

Tags: css

I read something that blow my mind and I want to ask if it possible or not.

According to the [w3school docs](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp) `content` attribute can take a `url` value which can be a **sound** ?!

> `url`(url)    Sets the content to be some kind of media (an image, a
>   sound, a video, etc.)

According to MDN

> The value is a URI that designates an external resource (such as an
>   image). If the resource or image can't be displayed, it is either
>   ignored or some placeholder shows up.

So I tried it

`content: url('http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.ogg');`

And nothing happens. My question is, **Is it indeed possible to trigger sound effects using CSS or it is just a mistake in w3schools docs** ?

**Edit: An example on when this could be useful**:

Of-course you can trigger sounds using JS, but there are cases that you are not allowed to use javascript or the user has not enabled javascript. So imagine that you serve an element to a third-website and you are allowed to use only HTML+CSS (e.g. a banner), if `content` indeed accepts sounds it would make possible to trigger sound effects on hover of pseudo elements.

Comment: Even if it did work, what would be the expected output? How would you even go about controlling the audio?

Comment: @noahnu trigger a sound effect on hover.

Comment: [the w3c writes](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/): `Another common effect is replacing elements with images or other multimedia content. Since not all user agents support all multimedia formats, fallbacks may have to be provided.`

Comment: @NicoO I updated, referring as w3school, thx!

Comment: It is well known that W3 Schools should not be trusted to have accurate or up to date information. Use MDN instead.

Comment: _"Is it indeed possible to trigger sound effects using CSS or it is just a mistake in w3schools docs?"_ Probably the latter

Comment: @ScottMarcus Maybe that was true three years ago but that's no longer true including from your original source.

Comment: @Rob It is still true today. Not sure what you mean by "my original source".

Comment: @ScottMarcus I presumed you heard of w3fools.com where everyone else first heard of their issues with it. w3fools no longer complains about w3schools and even considers it good for beginners.

Comment: No, I am not referring to that site. Despite what it may recommend, I teach IT in corporate environments and am constantly confronting inaccurate information suggested by my students that they got from W3 Schools. This is not just my opinion - it's well known. MDN is a much better resource.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[CSS2.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#content) says

> The value is a URI that designates an external
>   resource (such as an image). If the user agent cannot display the
>   resource it must either leave it out as if it were not specified or
>   display some indication that the resource cannot be displayed.

The old [CSS3 Generated and Replaced Content Module](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/#inserting3) working draft (2003) says

> if the URI is available and the format is supported, then the element
>   or pseudo-element becomes a replaced element, otherwise, the next item
>   in the comma separated list is used, if any.

The newer [CSS Generated Content Module Level 3](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-content-3/#content-uri) editor's draft (not ready for implementation) says basically the same:

> For URIs other than URIs in the last comma separated section of the
>   value, if the URI is available and the format is supported, then the
>   element or pseudo-element becomes a replaced element, otherwise, the
>   next item in the comma separated list is used, if any.

So it seems browsers may decide to support sound and render as a replaced element like `<audio>`. But most probably they won't.

Comment: If a browser did decide to support audio in `content`, I'd imagine it wouldn't be very effective without additional CSS properties to control the audio [attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio#Attributes).

Answer (score 2):

The [**W3C spec**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#contentl) reads slightly differently

> The value is a URI that designates an external resource (such as an image). If the user agent cannot display the resource it must either leave it out as if it were not specified or display some indication that the resource cannot be displayed.

There is no reference to *sound*...if it **were** possible, there is no indication as to how that would display/sound/activate...and, at best, at present, that would be up to the browser to implement.

So...arguably, W3Schools got it wrong....not for the first time.

Comment: The value of "media" is "all" and the link of "all" includes "sound" in "media types": https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html#all-media-group

Comment: @Rob doesn't that refer to the "media" your HTML/CSS is being rendered on? For use in `@media screen/print` etc...